# MuseScore 3: Play Different Instrument per Voice

Tags: voice, instruments, musescore

Is it possible to play different Instrument per voice In MuseScore 3?
[image]

**How to do it?**

Comment: Just to make sure I get your question right: Do you want to play (for examle) in voice two the first four #f as Piano and then the quarter/crotchet #f as guitar? And do you want to switch the instrument in the notation or in the sound?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this? I mean: sometimes people ask for something very specific since they don't realise there's a completely different, easier route to achieve the higher goal. (I.e. do you REALLY want to do this in musescore?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Instructions, text only

#### Choose your instrument

You need an instrument with multiple channels. For example, violin has three channels assigned to it: one for each of arco, pizzicato, and tremolo.

To do this,

1. right-click on an empty place in the first measure of the score.
2. select `Staff/Part Properties...`
3. click on the `Change Instrument...` button
4. select, for example, violin

#### Set the voices to separate channels

1. Click on the first note of the part.
2. In the master palette, select `Text > Staff text`.
3. In the element inspector (for the `staff text`) click the `Properties` button.
4. Set the voices to different channels. For example, Voice 1 to Arco and Voice 2 to Pizzicato.

#### In the mixer, change the sound for each channel

1. With the Violin (for example) slider selected, click on the right-arrow at the top to display the different channels.
2. Click on a channel slider and change the `Sound` setting to the instrument you want to hear.

## Instructions, with images

#### Step 0: set up the score

Here is a new score, created with a grand staff. The instrument (by default) is piano. The upper notes are Voice 1; the lower notes are Voice 2.

[image: Piano score with two voices in upper staff]

#### Step 1: Open the "Staff/Parts Properties" dialog box

At the beginning of the score, right click in a blank area of the staff whose voices you'd like to change instruments.

[image: Menu with "Staff/Parts Properties..." selected]

#### Step 2: Change the instrument for the (entire) staff.

1. In the "Part Properties" section of the "Staff/Part Properties" dialog box, click on the "Change Instrument..." button.

[image: "Staff/Part Properties..." Dialog box with "Change Instrument..." button selected]

2. Select a new instrument.

The instrument selected must be one with multiple channels assigned to it. This example uses Violin, which has three channels — enough for the two voices to be reassigned.

[image: Violin selected in instrument selection dialog box]

3. Click "OK" on both dialog boxes.

#### Step 3: Set Voice 1 and Voice 2 to different channels

1. Click on (i.e., select) the first note of Voice 1.
2. Add a Staff Text by clicking on the Text menu in the Master Palette and clicking "Staff Text".

[image: Image of "Staff Text" palette selection with Staff Text added to score]

3. With the "Staff Text" selected, click on "Staff Text > Properties" in the Element Inspector.

[image: "Properties" button displayed in Inspector]

4. On the "Change Channel" tab of the "Staff Text Properties" dialog box, set each voice to a different channel.

In this case, only Voice 1 and Voice 2 need to be set. In the image below, Voice 1 has already been set (to the "Arco" channel), and Voice 2 is about to be set (to the "Pizzicato" channel).

[image: Voice 2 and "Pizzicato" channel selected in dialog box]

#### Step 4: Use the Mixer to set each channel to a different sound

1. In the mixer, find the slider for the instrument to be reset (Violin in this example), and click the right-pointing arrow at the top of the control.

[image: Mixer image showing Master Gain and Violin sliders]

[image: Mixer image showing Master Gain and all Violin channel sliders]

2. Select a channel by clicking on its slider, and use the Mixer's "Sound" dropdown list to change the sound used when that channel (i.e., its associated Voice) is played.

[image: "Sound" control in Mixer]

[image: New sound selected in dropdown list]

[image: Selected sound shown in "Sound" control]

#### Step 5: Repeat the previous step for each channel that has been assigned to a Voice in the score.

#### Step 6: Play the score

Each voice will now sound as a separate instrument.

Comment: Thanks, Then the voice is depends on channel of instrument, but is not possible change the instrument per voice. According to your answer An image are valuable... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @joseluisbz That's right. A staff can only be assigned one instrument, but when that instrument has multiple channels, each voice within that instrumental part can be assigned to a separate channel, and then the sound for each channel can be set in the mixer. (My understanding is that instrument definitions can be changed to allow for what you're trying to do, but that's beyond my current know-how and would probably best be opened as a separate question.)

Comment: Considering the effort put in this answer, I think it deserves an up vote from the OP. I'll do it in the meantime!